# How to define set of routes dynamically in react based user access?

Tags: reactjs

I want to dynamically alter the routes based on user access level and I don't want to send routes which are not allowed for particular users to the front end.

for example, if I have two routes "/public" and "/private" and if the user does not have access to "/private" route I don't want that user to know there is route called "/private" available.

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically set where the route goes based on the user access. Something like this:

```
function App({user}){
  return (
    <a href={user === 'admin' ? 'private': 'public'} />
  );
}
```